# Reduce whitespace after table of figure title

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, tocloft

I'm working with a memoir based template and I have an list of figures which is just over a page in length. For page layout purposes it would be useful to remove some white-space between the list of figures title and the actual list to get this onto one page.[image: Demonstration on real world example] I have included what I think should be a MWE, with the solution I would expect to work from the [tocloft package](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) in comment. Uncommenting this gives me an undefined control sequence error for `\cftafterloftitleskip`. Can anyone tell me what my mistake is with this approach, or if the approach itself is wrong, how I should go about this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{capt-of}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}
\captionof{figure}{A}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need ` \newlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}` to remove the error but this does not solve the problem.  Anyway, for consistency with another chapter-like titles, is not a good idea remove spaces only in this page. What about simply `{\small\listoffigures}`?

Comment: It looks like the issue is the interaction between `memoir` and `tocloft`. If you use `book` instead, you get what you want. If you look at the log file after compiling with `book`, you'll see a line like `Package tocloft Info: The document has chapter divisions...`. If you compile with `memoir`, you'll see `Package tocloft [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.`

Comment: @TeXnician: As I noted, `tocloft` is being emulated by `memoir`, the actual implementation in `tocloft.sty` is not used.

Comment: @TH. You're right, I just was slow writing the comment, so I did not see yours beforehand. Just forgot the memoir emulation...

Comment: You can change the space after all chapter titles (and you probably do want them to be uniform across all chapters, including the list of figures), with `\setlength\afterchapskip{0pt}` (although that looks pretty bad).

Comment: @TH. Not bad ... the next. People often seem spaces around the title like wasted space, but they  are  more important that big bold font to make it stand out. Much better (IHMO, of course) reduce the interline space and/or reduce the font and/or split the list in  two columns if there are really enough short titles.

Comment: @Fran `{\small\listoffigures}` gives me a result that I'm happy with. Although this is more a work-around. Than an answer to the question it seems.
@TH. I'm afraid that in this case it is a mandated template based on memoir that I'm using. Changing the class will break a lot of stuff. `\setlength\afterchapskip{0pt}` seems to be what I was looking for, but you are right that it does not look good.

Comment: You can ping only one user at a time in comments, I think @TH. wasn't notified about the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memoir` class emulates the `tocloft` package but does so imperfectly. Thus lengths like `\cftafterloftitleskip` are not defined or used.

Instead of modifying just a single chapter (the List of Figures) which is likely to look strange since all of the other chapters will have different spacing, you can modify the spacing for all chapters.

I'm not sure that I recommend setting the layout of chapter headers based on the contents of a single chapter, but it is an option.

The two parameters which seem easiest to modify are `\beforechapskip` and `\afterchapskip`.

In your MWE, the list was two lines over so as a reasonable starting point, you might consider shrinking those two parameters a combined total of `2\baselineskip`. For example, putting `\addtolength\beforechapskip{-2\baselineskip}` in the preamble yields this.
[image: Image of the List of Figures]

Of course, you might choose to change `\beforechapskip` by -1.5\baselineskip and `\afterchapskip` by `.5\baselineskip`. In my (completely amateurish) opinion, reducing the space above the chapter header looks better than reducing the space below it.

(As an aside, when compiling this particular example, the list of figures isn't quite correct. Figure 0.1 is on page 2 and Figure 0.24 is on page 3. You also have to run `pdflatex` three times to get this result.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that every `\chapter` command writes `\addvspace{10pt}` to the `lof` file (and also `lot`).

Thus the `lof` file always begins with at least one `\addvspace{10pt}` that pushes the first caption down.

A solution is to add at the start a macro that recursively kills these unwanted vertical spaces.

The `openany` option is just to show the pages face to face; `lipsum` is for adding contents.

How does it work? The macro `\killaddvspace` checks whether the next token is `\addvspace` and, in this case it calls `\killedaddvspace` that gobbles `\addvspace{10pt}` and calls `\killaddvspace` again. When there's no more `\addvspace` lines to kill, the macro does nothing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\killaddvspace}{%
  \@ifnextchar\addvspace{\killedaddvspace}{}%
}
\newcommand{\killedaddvspace}[2]{\killaddvspace}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\killaddvspace}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Abstract}

\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{No figures}

\newcommand{\testchapter}{%
  \chapter{Test}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[3]
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[4]
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[5-8]
}

\testchapter
\testchapter
\testchapter
\testchapter
\testchapter

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I descided to accept TH's answer as it lies more closly inline with my original question which specified `\cftafterloftitleskip`. +1 for tackling the reason why the whitespace is larger than it should be. If I am correct, this will only work to bring the space after the list of figures title to the same size as other chapters? But, I guess you could add negative vspace to go even further?